# Converting `do notation` to >>= v. map

Tags: haskell

Given the following `do notation` code:

```
do
 a <- return 1
 b <- [10,20]
 return $ a+b
```

Is there a more idiomatic conversion:

```
ghci> return 1 >>= (\x -> map (+x) [10, 20])
[11,21]
```

versus

```
ghci> return 1 >>= (\x -> [10, 20] >>= (\y -> [y+x]))
[11,21]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`do` notation maps to monadic functions, so strictly you'd write

```
 return 1 >>= (\a -> [10, 20] >>= (\b -> return $ a+b ))
```

Now, you can replace that `>>= … return` by just [`fmap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:fmap)

```
 return 1 >>= (\x -> fmap (\y -> x+y) [10, 20])
```

and use sections, and scrap that constant `1` right into the function

```
 fmap (1+) [10, 20]
```

Alternatively, if you really want to take your first summand from a list, I'd recommend to use [`liftM2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM2):

```
 liftM2 (+) [1] [10, 20]
```

A bit more idiomatic than this, and with the same results, is the [`Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Applicative.html) instance of lists:

```
(+) <$> [1] <*> [10, 20]
```